# Filtering issue when override sales_order_grid to include Product name and discount amt in the Sales Order grid

Tags: sales-order

I have added Product name and Discount Amt in the Sales order grid. It is displayed properly. But my issue is filtering is not working on these columns.

The code of `my Grid.php` is like :

```
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}
protected function _getCollectionClass()
{
    return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->join(
            'sales/order_item',
            '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
            array(
                'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                )
            );
            $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfog' => 'sales_flat_order_grid'),'main_table.entity_id = sfog.entity_id',array('bill_name'=>'sfog.billing_name'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('bill_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'bill_name',
        //'filter_index' => 'sfog.billing_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('names', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product'),
        'index' => 'names',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('discount_amount', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount'),
        'index' => 'discount_amount',
    ));


    $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('bundle_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('bundlediscount');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete',array(
        'label'=>$this->_helper->__('Delete'),
        'url'=>$this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
        'confirm'=>'Are you sure?'
    ));
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status',array(
        'label'=>$this->_helper->__('Change Status'),
        'url'=>$this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus'),
        'additional'=>array(
            'visibility'=>array(
                'name'=>'status',
                'type'=>'select',
                'class'=>'required-entry',
                'label'=>$this->_helper->__('Status'),
                'values'=>array(
                    1=>$this->_helper->__('Enabled'),
                    0=>$this->_helper->__('Disabled'),
                )
            )
        )
    ));
     return parent::_prepareMassaction();
}
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
    }
    return false;
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}
}
?>
```

P.S.
I also tried using `filter_condition_callback` but it doesn't work. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to change 'index' => "bill_name" to index => "sfog.billing_name"

Comment: bill_name is an alias for sfog.billing_name, so its one & the same

Comment: Is there an error displayed when filtering?

Comment: Why have you commented out the filter index?

Comment: No, the filter is displayed fine.  filter_index doesnt affect filtering, so i removed it